# Проблема с импортом кириллицы из MetaTrader4 в С++

Tags: c++, dll, импорт, mql

Понятно, что есть файл export def function. Понятно, что dll должна лежать где надо. Всё это работает как надо.

Проблема только при выводе русских символов, см. код mql4

```
Print("test "+num+" (вот этот русский шрифт не импортируется в С++)");
```

Сторона dll, cpp

```
void logW(const wchar_t *text)
{
    static bool first = true;
    if (FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", first ? "w" : "a")) {
        first = false;
        fwprintf(file, text);
        fwprintf(file, L"\n");
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать отображение русского текста?

Comment: Текст у вас выводится в файл?

Comment: да, выводится всё кроме русских букв.

Comment: запакуйте файл с поломанными буквами в архив и выложите на обменник

Comment: Или необходимы hex коды русской строки. Видимо разные кодировки используются. А если приатачится в дебагере, что будет в переменой text?

Comment: Проблему так и не решил, лень было. Заменил всё на инглиш. Но предварительно сам MT4 режет кириллицу при использования c++ модулей. Может быть там реализовано только ansi кодировка.